# Unity Canvas Screen Space Overlay vs. Camera - Neither Works

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to learn Unity (specifically for 2D games) and having trouble with the UI. I would like for UI components to be rendered relative to the camera, on top of every other component. Unfortunately, neither the "Screen Space - Overlay" nor the "Screen Space - Camera" presets accomplish this.

When I set my canvas to Screen Space - Overlay, the canvas becomes massive and I cannot shrink it. I understand this is because my display size is thousands of pixels wide and Unity defaults to a camera that's only around 10 units wide, but shrinking my display isn't ideal and expanding all my components to fit this new size isn't really feasible either.

When I set my canvas to Screen Space - Camera, the canvas will now follow the camera like I wanted, but it renders the UI *behind* the components, not in front of them. The Canvas is fixed at Z position 90, and I can't change it. Moving all my components behind it to around Z 100 isn't feasible, and even if it was it wouldn't solve the underlying issue that objects can still render above the UI.

When I looked up solutions to the Overlay issue, the answer I kept getting was "Switch to Screen Space Camera". But when I looked up solutions to the Camera issue, people kept saying "Switch to Screen Space Overlay". How is there not a preset that fixes the UI to the camera, above the other components? Is there a workaround to either of these issues that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Just because the ui looks massive doesn't make it wrong

Comment: This was vague, but it was enough of a hint to get me on the right track. To anyone else in the future who has the same issue:

Screen Space - Overlay is the correct answer. For some reason the UI is placed a million miles away in the Scene view, but in the Game view it will render properly (i.e. on top of everything, and fixed to the camera). This means you have to do a solid 20 seconds of scrolling every time you want to edit UI in the Scene view, but c'est la vie I guess.

Comment: It's a true statement. You can click the 2d button which makes it a bit easier. Or click canvas and F possibly. But yes it is normal. Just cos its big doesnt make it wrong